# Find max halflife values relative to their temperature value in the same array

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

Basically I load the excel file into a pandas dataframe here:

```
dv = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
```

Then I clean it up and rename it to "cleaned" which is not important for this reproducible example, just mentioning for clarity:

```
if (selected_x.title()=="Viscosity" or selected_y.title()=="Viscosity"):
    cleaned = cleaned[cleaned.Study != "Yanqing Wang 2017"]
    cleaned = cleaned[cleaned.Study != "Thakore 2020"]
```

From there, I separate the cleaned dataframe into separate studies, this project is a composition of literature. I will include an example of two below:

```
yan = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Yanqing Wang 2017"]
tha = cleaned[cleaned.Study == "Thakore 2020"]
```

Finally, I load each of the individual studies into traces, and display them in a graph. Selected y and selected x are strings, such as "Temperature (C) " and "Halflife (Min)":

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(y=tha[selected_y], x=tha[selected_x])
trace2 = go.Scatter(y=yan[selected_y], x=yan[selected_x])
```

What I need to do is, after splitting the array into individual studies, find the maximum halflife relative to each temperature (0,50,100,150,200,250,300) and compile them into separate lists, then find the max value of these lists, take the whole row and append them into the same list. I have tried to do this using stuff like:

```
yan50 = yanq[yanq['Temperature (C) '] == 50]
yan100 = yanq[yanq['Temperature (C) '] == 100]
yan150 = yanq[yanq['Temperature (C) '] == 150]
yan200 = yanq[yanq['Temperature (C) '] == 200]
yan250 = yanq[yanq['Temperature (C) '] == 250]
yan300 = yanq[yanq['Temperature (C) '] == 300]
```

To split the study into the varying degree lists. I am currently stuck where I have to find the max value in halflife column of each list and add the whole corresponding row into a new list. This is what I am trying:

```
yan = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Study","Gas","Surfactant","Surfactant Concentration","Additive","Additive Concentration","LiquidPhase","Quality","Pressure (Psi)","Temperature (C) ","Shear Rate (/Sec)","Halflife (Min)","Viscosity","Color"])

if (len(yan50) > 0):
    yan50.loc[yan50['Halflife (Min)'].idxmax()]
    yan50 = yan50.dropna()
    yan.append(yan50)

if (len(yan100) > 0):
    yan100.loc[yan100['Halflife (Min)'].idxmax()]
    yan100 = yan100.dropna()
    yan.append(yan100)

if (len(yan150) > 0):
    yan150.loc[yan150['Halflife (Min)'].idxmax()]
    yan150 = yan150.dropna()
    yan.append(yan150)

if (len(yan200) > 0):
    yan200.loc[yan200['Halflife (Min)'].idxmax()]
    yan200 = yan200.dropna()
    yan.append(yan200)

if (len(yan250) > 0):
    yan250.loc[yan250['Halflife (Min)'].idxmax()]
    yan250 = yan250.dropna()
    yan.append(yan250)

if (len(yan300) > 0):
    yan300.loc[yan300['Halflife (Min)'].idxmax()]
    yan300 = yan300.dropna()
    yan.append(yan300)yan50.iloc[yan50['Halflife (Min)'].idxmax()]
```

The error I am getting is the individual temperature lists are empty.

I also got a bunch of Nan values for the separate temperature lists I compiled, and I am unsure if I am splitting the list correctly. I am not too strong with Pandas. Recommendations needed!

[Link to CSV of data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6f88tyo2fadri5/sample.csv?dl=0)

------------Edit-------------

[image]

What I have, all the studies placed on the same temp points (50, 100, etc). I want to find the maximum value of halflife, so that only the topmost point shows. The reason I am doing this is to aid in data-visualization. Future plans beyond this topic include: connecting the max value dots with a line and comparing the trends of the separate studies halflife values.

Comment: It is very hard to create a table with the data you posted. can you put that in a `csv` file & provide a link to that CSV file? This is a not recommended process however, with you data I am unable to create a pandas dataframe that i can work on.

Comment: Done, let me know if I can add anything else

Comment: In the `csv` you provided, there only one study 'Thakore 2020'. Also, it not clear what you want to achieve. So, with the limited info, i suggest you try one the 2 below lines of code & see if you get what you want. `df.groupby(['Study','Temperature (C) '])['Halflife (Min)'].max().reset_index(name='Max_halflife')` or `df['Max_halflife'] = df.groupby(['Study','Temperature (C) '])['Halflife (Min)'].transform('max')`. With the 2nd code, you get a column named `Max_halflife` which has the max hallife for each temperature within each study (you will have to print the df with print(df) to see it).

Comment: Ok i will try. What I hope to achieve is take a study array like yan (which is the list that is comprised of only rows that contain the yanqing study, which was derived from the array cleaned that has all of the studies in it) and break it up into several lists. One that contains all rows at 50 degrees. One with all rows that have 100 degrees, etc. Then, find the index of the row that has the max halflife value in each of those temp specific lists and add it to a new list. I need to do this for all temps.

Comment: fixed the csv, added yanqing study data

Comment: I will update the post with more practical details of why I need to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, what you need is

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Study','Temperature (C) '])['Halflife (Min)'].max().reset_index(name='Max_halflife')
```

This will result in

```
          Study     Temperature (C)     Max_halflife
0   Thakore 2020                 50     120.00
1   Thakore 2020                100     2.40
2   Thakore 2020                150     0.20
3   Yanqing Wang 2017            50     123.00
4   Yanqing Wang 2017           100     3.20
5   Yanqing Wang 2017           150     0.31
```

Then the code below should get you the graph you wnat.

```
import seaborn as sns
df2 = df.groupby(['Study','Temperature (C) '])['Halflife (Min)'].max().reset_index(name='Max_halflife')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
sns.scatterplot(x='Temperature (C) ', y='Max_halflife', data=df2, hue='Study')
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Stupid question, but how did you get such close together numbers on your graph? I have a max of 200 halflife for Yanqing at 100 degrees...your graph appears much nicer than mine

Comment: Your graph follows the trend I am looking for, and for some reason I am not getting the same numbers for Yanqing

Comment: I get a loading error when i try to open the CSV file. So, i added some dummy data. So, the values will not correspond to your data, it is just dummy data for study `Yanqing Wang 2017`

Comment: Hahaha, well nicely done. Very accurate number work. Appreciate the answer!